# PowerCLI New-CDDrive - invalid datastore path

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to mount an iso from a datastore using VMWare PowerCLI. Code example:

```
$IsoPath = "vmstores:\1.2.2.1900443\datacenter1\datastore1\files.iso"
$cd = New-CDDrive -VM Vm001 -ISOPath $IsoPath
```

This fails with the error: `New-CDDrive     The operation for the entity "Vm001" failed with the following message: "Invalid datastore path 'vmstores:\1.2.2.1900443\datacenter1\datastore1\files.iso'`

The path is valid. I confirm with:

```
Get-ChildItem "vmstores:\1.2.2.1900443\datacenter1\datastore1\files.iso"
```

Output:

```
Name               Type               Id
----               ----               --
Files.iso          DatastoreFile
```

What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the `vmstores:` drive is a [PowerShell Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-6) available on your local system, but the VHost has no idea about it, and the path needs to be in the form it understands, e.g. `'[DatastoreName] folder\folder2\file.iso'`.